# Making Cells Blank for Hidden Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm brand new to VBA and am trying to optimize a spreadsheet for work.

Ultimately, I'm trying to write a script that looks for hidden rows.  If a row is hidden, then the cell in column "O" in that row should be blank.  Here's what I have (that is not working and may be completely wrong):

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A1500")
For Each c In rng
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    End If
Next c
```

Thank you for your help!
Kim

Comment: Are you getting an error? Does it not do what you want?

Comment: I'm not getting an error; I'm just not getting what I want.

Comment: Then what do you want?

Comment: I want the cell in column O of any hidden rows to become blank if they aren't already.

Comment: That's for the suggestion.  I appreciate it and will research it as I'm learning to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer to loop through with long integers and avoid ActiveCells.  Turn off screen updating as well if it's going to be long.

```
Dim c As Long

For c = 1 To 1500
    If Rows(c).Hidden = True Then
        Cells(c, "O") = ""
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Good answer but could you qualify the parent worksheet (seeing as how this is a teaching exercise in proper coding)?

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  However, for some reason when I run it, it makes a specific row (#81) unhidden when it previously wasn't.  So weird.  I'm going to look back in my code to see if there's any conflicting commands.  Can you think of anything that would cause that?

Comment: `Rows` and `Cells` implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet` if this is written in a standard module, or implicitly refer to `Me` if this is written in a worksheet code-behind. Because the meaning is different depending on context, it's critical to systematically qualify these calls with a proper `Worksheet` object instance. Upvoted for using `Long` and avoiding `ActiveCell`. Also note, `If {bool} = True Then` is redundant, just do `If {bool} Then`, i.e. `If ActiveSheet.Rows(c).Hidden Then`

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help, Liss!

Comment: Mat's Mug: I honestly don't know enough about VBA to make sense of your explanation.  I have a manual coming in this weekend.  Once I read through it, I will come back to your comment to understand it.  Thank you for your thorough explanation.  I'm looking forward to exploring and understanding VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just tested this and it works:

```
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim c As Range

  Set rng = Range("A1:A1500")
  For Each c In rng
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
      Range("O" & c.Row).Value = ""
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: fwiw, `vbNullString` is slightly faster than using `""` to represent a zero-length string (i.e. blank).

Comment: @khelm Updated answer. Fully tested.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no formulas and you want a non-loop-solution, you simply can run this 1-liner:

```
Range("O1:O1500") = Evaluate("INDEX(IF(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(O1,ROW(O1:O1500)-1,)),O1:O1500,""""),)")
```

The `OFFSET` will just return a lot of `#VALUE!` which still have a single-cell-ref. This is the key for having `SUBTOTAL` to output an array (instead of a single value) which with option `3` just returns 1 for all items inside the array while having `option + 100` will exclude hidden rows. Using this inside the `IF` will simply be `true` for visible rows and `false` for hidden ones. Now `true` returns the cells value while `false` only returns a simple empty string. The `INDEX` is just for forcing the `Evaluate` to return an array which then simply is set for the range. Everything in one calculation without any loop :D